# To what level of the EMV stack does the Android NFC API provide?

Tags: android, nfc, emv

I've been trying to learn about EMV by implementing the contactless protocol on Android. I have read the level 1 (physical layer) EMV Contactless specification and was expecting to need to implement most of it, however the data given by the android NFC API was not what I was expecting.

What layers of the EMV Contactless protocol does the Android NFC API implement? And where should I look within the EMV specification for the next level to implement?

Many thanks

Comment: Do you know what a protocol is?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the normal Android developer it implements ISO/IEC 7816-4 (NFC Forum Type 4) with Host Card Emulation which EMV Contactless also use.

So you can implement an AID's (Application ID's). Different AID's are used by different EMV providers.

But I'm sure more is done in the secure element which only Google wallet can access.